# Using BeelabTagBundle library on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, tags

I am trying to use [BeelabTagBundle](https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) library to implements tags on my website. But I am in a lack of information to do so. Here is where I am at now:

- Installed via composer
- Created an entity that implements "TaggableInterface" with some personals fields, and the requested ones in the documentation.

---

```
 /**
  * Constructor
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->keywords = new ArrayCollection();
 }
 /**
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 protected $id = null;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
 private $type;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
 private $fileName;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
  */
 private $active;

 /**
  * @var ArrayCollection
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
  */
 private $keywords;

 private $tagsText;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
  */
 private $updated;

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function addTag(TagInterface $tag)
 {
     $this->keywords[] = $tag;
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function removeTag(TagInterface $tag)
 {
     $this->keywords->removeElement($tag);
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function hasTag(TagInterface $tag)
 {
     return $this->keywords->contains($tag);
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function getTags()
 {
     return $this->keywords;
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function getTagNames(): array
 {
     return empty($this->tagsText) ? [] : array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->tagsText));
 }

 /**
  * @param string
  */
 public function setTagsText($tagsText)
 {
     $this->tagsText = $tagsText;
     $this->updated = new \DateTime();
 }

 /**
  * @return string
  */
 public function getTagsText()
 {
     $this->tagsText = implode(', ', $this->keywords->toArray());
     return $this->tagsText;
 }
```

- Have my route to get the json of my tags (working when calling it but empty)

---

```
 /**
  * @Route("/miseenpage/keywords.json", name="keywords", defaults={"_format": "json"})
  */
 public function tagsAction() {
     $tags = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Tag::class)->findBy([], ['name' => 'ASC']);
     return $this->render('miseenpage/keywords.html.twig', ['tags' => $tags]);
 }
```

- I also followed the [Javascript enhancement](https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/javascript.md), So I now have created a "TagsTextType"

---

```
 class TagsTextType extends AbstractType
 {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
         $builder
             ->add('tagsText', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Tags'])
         ;
     }

     /**
      * @var RouterInterface $route
      */
     private $router;

     /**
      * @param RouterInterface $router
      */
     public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
     {
         $this->router = $router;
     }

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults([
             'required' => false,
             'label' => 'Tags',
             'attr' => [
                 'placeholder' => 'separate tags with comma',
                 'data-ajax' => $this->router->generate('keywords'),
             ],
         ]);
     }

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function getParent()
     {
         return TextType::class;
     }
 }
```

How can I show my tag field now (alongside with all my other data from my entity) ? This is not detailed in the documentation. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a javascript library called `select2`, see : https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle/blob/master/docs/javascript.md